# Can we have centralized helm charts repo for all microservices

Tags: azure-pipelines, microservices, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, cicd, helm3

Our team is developing an application based on microservices architecture. And will be deployed on Kubernetes using helm chart.

We will be using Azure DevOps to manage the project as well as Pipelines. 
And took reference from the below URL for managing CI/CD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/ci-cd-kubernetes

[image: Azure CI/CD pipeline for microservices]

**We have 2 scenarios as follows for managing Helm chart:**

1. **Should we have a centralized repository for the helm chart, where we will have the sub-charts per microservice?**

- In this case, we can have only one release pipeline which will use this centralized Helm chart repository to upgrade changes in Kubernetes.
- Here we have an issue in the CI pipeline's `Helm package` job which only allows us to select the chart within the microservice repository for which the pipeline is created.
  I think we can solve this by creating a separate pipeline for the `Helm package and Push` jobs so we can select the chart from the centralized Helm repository. And this pipeline will be common for all the microservices and will trigger after the CI pipeline.

**OR**

2. **Should we have a charts within the corresponding microservice repositories?**

- In this case, we need to have a separate Release pipeline for each microservice.
- Also manage helm charts individually.
- How to manage deployment for integration testing on a QA environment if there are changes in 2 or more microservices. As each service will be deployed individually how this is going to be in sync?

Please suggest us the best/recommended way so we move ahead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give us suggestions so we can decide which option to choose.

Answer (score 0):

If your **microservices** have *common configurations* with *slight differences*, then a centralized repository makes sense. But I wouldn't recommend having a parent helm chart with sub-charts for each microservice.

It is better to build a helm chart as a template so that you can introduce different values for each microservice deployment. Sub-charts are generally useful when microservices have common requirements such as databases or key-value storage services.

On the other side **mono-repo** would simplify your release pipelines by filtering changes for microservices with a directory structure as follows:

./microservices:

- payment
- shipping
- ...

For the QA environment, I would keep multiple versions of the same microservice deployment simultaneously so that there wouldn't be a bottleneck while performing tests. This is also valid for the production environment since one cannot be sure that all dependencies are always up-to-date.

As an alternative helm charts can be located in a different repository. The microservice repository only builds and pushes container images. Gitops operator like Flux/ArgoCD triggers deployment when helm chart versions are updated.

If you choose canary deployment, both Flagger and ArgoCD provide built-in smoke testing features.